# Instance already started issue

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb, fusefabric

I am unable to start or stop the fabric container, I am getting the error. Please find the below screen shots.

[fabric Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFFJ.jpg) 
[Error while starting and stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ5lU.jpg)

Comment: You could try `container-start` or `container-stop` with the `--force` switch. It may be necessary to kill the container at the operating system level, and then forcibly start it. There are a number of problems that can cause a container's state to become unsynchronized across the fabric, but these require meticulous investigation -- probably beyond the scope of a SO post

Comment: After trying above commands, I tried fabric:status now its working fine.

Comment: OK. Ideally, you should try to find out (by careful inspection of logs, etc) how this situation arose. In an up-to-date Fuse, it should really be necessary to `--force` operations.

Comment: @Kelvin Boone, please find the logs for root:    2017-10-13 17:41:40,931 | WARN  | 1785701161-11897 | Response                         | 86 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | Committed before 404 null
2017-10-13 17:41:40,932 | WARN  | 1785701161-11897 | AbstractHttpConnection           | 86 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | /maven/download/com/act/esb/createUpdateWorkOrder-

Comment: @kelvin child container logs :   2017-10-13 19:39:03,520 | WARN  | p1164596842-6977 | ServletHandler                   | 103 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | Error for /jolokia/
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)[:1.8.0_60]
 at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:671)[:1.8.0_60]
 at

Comment: sorry, this problem needs detailed analysis, of a kind that is not really suitable for the notes attached to a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I tried to kill the instance by using container-stop --force  issue still persists. So, first I stopped the server then I checked the list of process which are using java by using ps -ef | grep -i java, then got to know that one java process is still running with -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote property and whose process id is equal to item.0.pid in (item.0 in this 0 will be first container number, ideally once the server stopped item.< X >.pid=0, if its not equal to 0 then its a heap space issue) ${karaf.home}/instance/instace.properties , immediately I killed that process then I started the server now everything worked fine for me. The only reason why I got this issue is java heap space issue.